# How to expand zip to incorporate 3 lists

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I need to expand the following code in order to incorporate 3 lists.

```
for a, b in zip(product_old, product_name):
    print('{:<6} {}'.format(a, b))
```

However when I expand to:

```
for a, b, c in zip(product_old, product_name, product_new):
    print('{:<6} {}'.format(a, b, c))
```

The returned print does not include the new list. How can I fix this? I have tried DataFrame, however this isn't suitable due to the fact there doesn't seem to be an option to left justify the data.

Thank you!

Comment: Copy/paste error, please check again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapt this sample code to get what you want:

```
product_old = ["a", "b"]
product_name = ["c", "d"]
product_new = ["e", "f"]

for a, b, c in zip(product_old, product_name, product_new):
    print("{:<6} {:<6} {:<6}".format(a, b, c))
```

Output:

```
a      c      e     
b      d      f
```

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, your second `format()` string uses only two place-holders but passed in three which won't work.

Comment: Apologies, this was a copy/paste issue, not a code issue. Please see updated code.